# Adicionando valores ao HashMap <Integer, List<Integer>> e buscando-os através do key?

Tags: android, loop, hashmap

Eu estou fazendo um aplicativo focado para vendedores externos. 1 vendedor externo possui vários clientes, e também vários produtos, que é comercializado livremente com estes clientes. Estes produtos nem sempre permanecem no mesmo valor (descontos, impostos, etc), logo, o aplicativo possui uma função de cálculos.

*Resumidamente: 1 cliente possui N produtos, e N produtos possuem N cálculos.*

Porém, eu travei numa parte do meu projeto que eu preciso exibir todos os os cálculos de um respectivo produto de um respectivo cliente. Bom, meu código até agora é **este**:

```
private List<Integer> ids;
private List<Integer> allValues;
private List<Calculos> calculosItems;
private List<Calculos> produtosSemRedundancia; //usado para exibir na ListView


private List<Calculos> RemoverDuplicados()
{
    //inicializa as variáveis
    allValues.clear();
    idQuantidadeProdutos.clear();
    idQuantidadeCalculos.clear();


    //separa os cálculos repetidos e envia para a lista auxiliar;
    for(Calculos i : calculosItems)
    {
        int valor = Integer.parseInt(i.getId_produto());
        if (valor == 1)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "encontrei o ID 1! ADDing calc: " + i.get_id());
            testeList.put(valor, new ArrayList<Integer>(i.get_id()));
        }

        //Exibindo todos os produtos & os respectivos cálculos que estão dentro do ID produtos.
        Log.d(TAG, "X Produto ID: " + i.getId_produto() + "- Calculo ID: " + i.get_id());

        allValues.add(Integer.valueOf(i.getId_produto()));

        //se variável 'ids' não tiver o valor do ID do produto, eu adiciono aqui
        if(!ids.contains(Integer.valueOf(i.getId_produto())))
        {
            testeList.put(Integer.valueOf(i.getId_produto()), new ArrayList<Integer>(i.get_id()));
            produtosSemRedundancia.add(i);
            ids.add(Integer.valueOf(i.getId_produto()));
        }


    }

    try
    {
        //identifica quantos cálculos cada produto tem & adiciona no Map "idQuantidadeProdutos".
        for (Integer id : ids)
        {
            idQuantidadeProdutos.put(id, Collections.frequency(allValues, id));
        }

    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}

    //aqui eu exibo todos meus produtos e quanto cálculos cada produto tem. O ideal seria exibir qual é o ID de cada
    //um destes cálculos.
    final String format = "Produto ID: %d possui: %d calculos";
    final Set<Integer> chaves = idQuantidadeProdutos.keySet(); // as chaves são os ids
    for (final Integer chave : chaves)
        Log.d(TAG, String.format(format, chave, idQuantidadeProdutos.get(chave)));


    return produtosSemRedundancia;
}
```

Estes são os valores:

```
Produto ID: 1- Calculo ID: 14
Produto ID: 1- Calculo ID: 15
Produto ID: 1- Calculo ID: 16
Produto ID: 2- Calculo ID: 17
Produto ID: 8- Calculo ID: 18
Produto ID: 8- Calculo ID: 19
Produto ID: 8- Calculo ID: 20
Produto ID: 2- Calculo ID: 21
Produto ID: 6- Calculo ID: 23
Produto ID: 6- Calculo ID: 24
Produto ID: 6- Calculo ID: 25
Produto ID: 4- Calculo ID: 26
Produto ID: 1- Calculo ID: 27
```

E este é o output que diz qual é o ID do produto & quantos cálculos ele tem, como a seguir:

```
Produto ID: 4 possui: 1 calculos
Produto ID: 8 possui: 3 calculos
Produto ID: 1 possui: 4 calculos
Produto ID: 6 possui: 3 calculos
Produto ID: 2 possui: 2 calculos
```

O problema é que cada um destes cálculos possui um ID, e eu não sei como armazená-los dentro da minha lógica e pesquisá-los depois (passando o ID do cliente e ID do produto, daí ele me retorna todos os IDs dos cálculos).

Por exemplo, se o cliente clicasse no produto do ID 1, ele teria que me retornar isso:

```
Produto ID: 1 possui: 4 calculos com os IDs: [14, 15, 16, 27]
```

Alguém pode me ajudar ou sugerir algo, por favor? Estou há dias perdido nisso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue a lógica: Abaixo é está o método para preencher com id do produto e o cálculo.

```
Map<integer, List<Integer>> mapProdutoCalculo= new HashMap<integer, List<Integer>>();

public void adicionarCalculo(Integer idProduto, Integer calculo){
  if(map.containsKey(idProduto)){
     map.get(idProduto).add(calculo);
  }else{
     List<Integer>> lista = new ArrayList();
     lista.add(calculo);
     map.put(idProduto,lista);
  }
}
```

Utilização : Quando o usuário tocar no produto de id 1, basta você fazer

```
List<Integer>> calculos = map.get(idProduto);
```

a variável calculos tem todo os cálculos daquele produto.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vou testar agora mesmo (desculpe a demora, estava descansando esse fds e nem toquei no pc, hehe).

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado cara, você me salvou!!

Comment: novamente cara, muito obrigado!!!!!!!

Comment: De nada! [StayCoding]